# Android Button in LinearLayout Fit Left

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

[image: I want to do]

I want to put button like above picture. But I have below image. I can't success this. Search a lot of but can't find it.

[image: result of code]

LinearLayout in LinearLayout has transparent background and there is button left of this.

Activity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/genel_arkaplan"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="750dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/lay_transparan_aramasecenek"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lay_transparan_aramasecenek_beyaz">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/kod_ile_arama"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change height and width to `match_parent` for second `Linearlayout`. Button doesn't need `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` also remove _android:paddingLeft="40dp"_

Comment: I do it but I have space left,top and bottom. Can you share final xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `android:paddingLeft="40dp` from **LinearLayout** Tag

Comment: Removed but I still have spaces between linearlayouts

Comment: You are using margins also take the same cornors for below layout and button then it ll fit properly.. let me know once done else ll give you another solution

Comment: Okay Thanks I have solved problem. lay_transparan_aramasecenek layout has margin top,bottom,left. I removed margins no problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: @mobileprogramming glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Just remove below code from your "LinearLayout"

```
android:paddingLeft="40dp"
```

This is adding extra padding to your parent layout.

Below will be your final code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/genel_arkaplan"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="750dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/lay_transparan_aramasecenek"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/lay_transparan_aramasecenek_beyaz">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/kod_ile_arama"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for batter result for your Button Icon. I Hope it is helpful for You.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_green"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_50"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_share"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```